# Filter data in react based on parent prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

How do I filter data in a component based on a parent prop?

My data to compare to contains something like:

```
{
   "id": "5a7847508f9337cf77712128",
   "index": 0,
   "projectName": "Ovolo",
   "location": "Stoddard Place, Riverton, New York, 3571"
},
{
   "id": "5a7847503101a8ef7f7d3c30",
   "index": 1,
   "projectName": "Isonus",
   "location": "Elliott Walk, Magnolia, Minnesota, 4488"
}...
```

My component looks something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import data from "../data/projects.json";

const ProjectTitle = data.filter((projects, props) => {
    if (projects.id === props.project_id ) 
    var title = projects.projectName;
    return title;
});

class ProjectName extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            projectTitle: ProjectTitle
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        projectTitle: ProjectTitle
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h4 className="projectName">
                { this.state.projectTitle }
            </h4>
        );
    }
}

export default ProjectName;
```

Basically, I want to match props.project_id from the parent component with the first project from my data that matches the id, so I can display the projectName using the component. Currently, the one that I tried does not return the name of the project. I am new to this so I need help and guidance, maybe an example or a reference may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you wants to watch for different project_id sent from the parent and depending on which want to filter the data, as far as i understood.

One thing you can do is use componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle to watch for new props. and can also componentDidMount lifecycle to set the projecttitle.

you need to change the projectTitle function also

```
const ProjectTitle = (projectId) => {
  const project = data.filter((projects) => {
    if (projects.id === projectId ) {
       return true;
    }
    return false
});
if(project) {
  return projects.projectName;
}
return project
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   const {project_id} = nextProps
   const newProjectTitle = ProjectTitle(project_id)
   this.setState({
    projectTitle: newProjectTitle,
   })
}

componentDidMount() {
const {project_id} = this.props
   const newProjectTitle = ProjectTitle(project_id)
   this.setState({
    projectTitle: newProjectTitle,
   })
}
```

> By adding componentWIllReceiveprops and componentDidMount you can
>   dynamically change the project name whenever new project_id is passed
>   as a props. you can also use the constructor function  to initialize the state like this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props) 
    this.state = {
    projectTitle: ProjectTitle(props.project_id),
 }
}
```

Refer this [lifecycle methods in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting) for more reference

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it isn't working exactly but that `ProjectTitle` that you create outside the class doesn't ring well with me. I think that you're assigning it to the state and that's not working as expected. You should do the filter (or find) operation in the componentWillMount function of the [React lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) . After you find the project you do the setState and it should work.

```
class ProjectName extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.state = {
                projectTitle: ''
            }
        }

        componentWillMount() {
          const project = data.find(project => project.id === this.props.project_id);
          if (project) {
              this.setState({
                projectTitle: project.projectName
              });
          }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <h4 className="projectName">
                    {this.state.projectTitle}
                </h4>
            );
        }
    }

    export default ProjectName;
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers; add a brief description of what you've changed to answer this question.

Comment: The code looks correct but I think explaining what the OP had incorrect would get you an upvote ;)

Comment: This will not work if the component updates, you need to replicate the logic in the `componentWillReceiveProps` callback and check if the project_id will change, and if so update the state. It's also better to move this logic the the component's constructor instead of `componentWillMount`

Comment: @TiagoHenriqueEngel The updating and componentWillReceiveProps looks outside the scope of that OP is asking if you ask me. If needed it can be done of course.

Comment: Well, that's one way of looking at it. You're suggesting he/she implements a solution that won't work. I consider this within the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `props.project_id` is a ProjectName's prop the easiest solution is to move the filter to the render function. Also, if you want to find one record use `find` not `filter`.

```
render() {
    const project = data.find(( {id} ) => id === this.props.project_id)
    return (
        <h4 className="projectName">
            { project && project.title }
        </h4>
    );
}
```

You could do as other suggested and set the state during the component's creation, but then you'd have to do the same in `componentWillReceiveProps`, this creates a lot of unnecessary complexity.

If performance is an issue (it generally isn't) and you want to find the project only once per id, use a `memoized` function and keep the logic in the render function. This is a lot simpler and has the same effect.